How to fix ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/gasket-dkms.0.crash' in Ubuntu 22.04 machine?
Hey In my node application I have a INSTALL.sh file where I have the below code :
#!/bin/bash
ARCH=$(uname -m)
if [ -x "$(command -v apt)" ]; then
    echo "Install Coral TPU Drivers?"
    echo "(y)es or (N)o"
    read installTheStuffHomie
    if [ "$installTheStuffHomie" = "y" ] || [ "$installTheStuffHomie" = "Y" ]; then
        echo "Installing Coral TPU Drivers..."
        echo "deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt coral-edgetpu-stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/coral-edgetpu.list

        curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

        sudo apt-get update -y
        sudo apt-get install gasket-dkms libedgetpu1-std -y
        sudo sh -c "echo 'SUBSYSTEM==\"apex\", MODE=\"0660\", GROUP=\"apex\"' >> /etc/udev/rules.d/65-apex.rules"

        sudo groupadd apex

        sudo adduser $USER apex
        sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev -y
        sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y
        pip3 install Cython
        pip3 install Pillow==9.5.0

        if [ "$ARCH" = "x86_64" ]; then
            # for x86/x64
            echo "x86/x64 tflite runtime Installing..."
            wget https://cdn.shinobi.video/installers/python3/2023-10-12/tflite_runtime-2.5.0.post1-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl
            pip3 install tflite_runtime-2.5.0.post1-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl
            rm tflite_runtime-2.5.0.post1-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl
        elif [ "$ARCH" = "aarch64" ]; then
            # for arm
            echo "AARCH64 tflite runtime Installing..."
            wget https://cdn.shinobi.video/installers/python3/2023-10-12/tflite_runtime-2.5.0-cp310-cp310-linux_aarch64.whl
            pip3 install tflite_runtime-2.5.0-cp310-cp310-linux_aarch64.whl
            rm tflite_runtime-2.5.0-cp310-cp310-linux_aarch64.whl
        else
            echo "Architecture : $ARCH"
            echo "Trying to install tflite runtime from apt..."
            sudo apt-get install python3-pycoral -y
            pip3 install --extra-index-url https://google-coral.github.io/py-repo/ pycoral
        fi
        # for both x86/x64 and arm
        wget https://cdn.shinobi.video/installers/python3/2023-10-12/pycoral-2.0.0-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl
        pip3 install pycoral-2.0.0-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl
        rm pycoral-2.0.0-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl

        chown root:apex /dev/apex_0 && chmod 777 /dev/apex_0
        echo "------------------------------"
        echo "Reboot is required. Do it now?"
        echo "------------------------------"
        echo "(y)es or (N)o. Default is No."
        read rebootTheMachineHomie
        if [ "$rebootTheMachineHomie" = "y" ] || [ "$rebootTheMachineHomie" = "Y" ]; then
            sudo reboot
        fi
    fi
else
    echo "Debian based systems can only install this driver. Try Ubuntu 22.04.3."
fi


For testing it's working, I run the choose to run the file by clicking y in UI and it starts to get downloading. But When the gasket-dkms package portion comes
it gets failed and throws error as below:
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gasket-dkms
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/48.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 256 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package gasket-dkms.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 285272 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gasket-dkms_1.0-18_all.deb ...
Unpacking gasket-dkms (1.0-18) ...
Setting up gasket-dkms (1.0-18) ...
Loading new gasket-1.0 DKMS files...
Building for 6.5.0-26-generic 6.5.0-27-generic
Building initial module for 6.5.0-26-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/gasket-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/gasket/1.0/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package gasket-dkms (--configure):
 installed gasket-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gasket-dkms
The user `root' is already a member of `apex'.
Reading package lists...

As per suggestions given, I have seen the make.log file using the below command:
 cat /var/lib/dkms/gasket/1.0/build/make.log

The below is the result:
DKMS make.log for gasket-1.0 for kernel 6.5.0-27-generic (x86_64)
Wednesday 10 April 2024 12:31:12 PM IST
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-27-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/gasket/1.0/build/gasket_core.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/gasket/1.0/build/gasket_ioctl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/gasket/1.0/build/gasket_interrupt.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/gasket/1.0/build/gasket_page_table.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/gasket/1.0/build/gasket_sysfs.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/gasket/1.0/build/apex_driver.o
/var/lib/dkms/gasket/1.0/build/gasket_core.c: In function ‘gasket_register_device’:
/var/lib/dkms/gasket/1.0/build/gasket_core.c:1841:41: error: passing argument 1 of ‘class_create’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
 1841 |                 class_create(driver_desc->module, driver_desc->name);
      |                              ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
      |                                         |
      |                                         struct module *
In file included from ./include/linux/device.h:31,
                 from ./include/linux/cdev.h:8,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/gasket/1.0/build/gasket_core.h:11,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/gasket/1.0/build/gasket_core.c:12:
./include/linux/device/class.h:230:54: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘struct module *’
  230 | struct class * __must_check class_create(const char *name);
      |                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
/var/lib/dkms/gasket/1.0/build/gasket_core.c:1841:17: error: too many arguments to function ‘class_create’
 1841 |                 class_create(driver_desc->module, driver_desc->name);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/device/class.h:230:29: note: declared here
  230 | struct class * __must_check class_create(const char *name);
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:251: /var/lib/dkms/gasket/1.0/build/gasket_core.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-27-generic/Makefile:2039: /var/lib/dkms/gasket/1.0/build] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-27-generic'


I have also tried uninstalling the package using the below command and tried running the INSTALL.sh file again but it didn't work.
sudo apt remove gasket-dkms

I need help to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1500017/ubuntu-22-04-default-gcc-version-does-not-match-version-that-built-latest-defaul

Looks like gasket driver(s) has not been updated for Linux kernel of version 6, where signature of class_create has been changed.

The gasket driver was fixed upstream to handle the class_create API change in kernel 6.4.
